# how to get the value of the dropdown jquery

Tags: php, jquery, dom

I want to get the value of the dropdown. I am using msDropDown, but i am getting its value as undefined.  The html as follows:

```
 <select name="category[]" 
         id="webmenus_<?php echo $BPackageCityRelatedToCountry[$i]['city_id']; ?>"      
         onchange="showValue(this.value)"
 >
     <option value="0" selected="selected" title="Please select hotel category"></option>
     <option value="5_<?php echo $BPackageCityRelatedToCountry[$i]['city_id']; ?>" title="/public/front_end/images/5star.png"></option>
     <option value="4_<?php echo $BPackageCityRelatedToCountry[$i]['city_id']; ?>" title="/public/front_end/images/4star.png"></option>
     <option value="3_<?php echo $BPackageCityRelatedToCountry[$i]['city_id']; ?>" title="/public/front_end/images/3star.png"></option>
     <option value="2_<?php echo $BPackageCityRelatedToCountry[$i]['city_id']; ?>" title="/public/front_end/images/2star.png"></option>
     <option value="1_<?php echo $BPackageCityRelatedToCountry[$i]['city_id']; ?>" title="/public/front_end/images/1star.png"></option>
</select>
```

`jquery  alert($("input[name='category[]']").val());` alerts as undefined.

How can i get the value of the dropdown?
Thanks,

Comment: $("input[name='category[]']") is going to return multiple results isnt it?  Do you not need to have this instead $("input[name='category[]']")[0].val()

Comment: Well, you use `input` in your selector, but in your HTML you have a `select` element.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with name that has a syntax from an array?

Comment: @reporter: It's commonly used to send multiple values with the same name to PHP. It recognises the `[]` and creates an array for those values.

Comment: @Felix I see. Tell if I'm wrong, but can you achive the same if you give all form fields the same name (ok, you have to decrlare explicit that you get multiple values).

Comment: @reporter: You mean just `name="category"` for multiple fields? No, unfortunately this does not work with PHP. It will only get the last value then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use **select** instead of **input**

Edit your HTML and set the select Tag to mutiple

```
 <select name="test" multiple>
     <option value="1">ITEM 1</option>
      <option value="2">ITEM 2</option>
      <option value="3">ITEM 3</option>
  </select>

alert($('select[name="test"]').val());
// outputs 1,2,3 when you select all three options
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(":input[name='category[]']").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $("class of select ").change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: or  `$('class of select ').val($(this).find(":selected").val());`

Comment: Why are you using a change event? The OP didn't ask for this. What if they want to get the value from another function, such as a link click event?

Comment: The comment does not make a lot of sense... what is `this` in that case?

Comment: @FelixKling its the $('class of select ')

Comment: So you are setting the value of the select to the value of the selected option? That still does not make sense... It's the same as writing `$(foo).val($(foo).val())`. It just sets the value to what it already has.

Comment: I took the image dropdown from here http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown